# Very specyfic linear order not isomorphic with $\langle\mathbb N,\le\rangle$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, relations

Give an example of a numerable linear order such that each element has a successor, there is the smallest element, each element except the smallest one has a predecessor, but the order is not isomorphic with $\langle\mathbb N,\le\rangle$.

I understand it all, but I can't come up with anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider $\Bbb N$ followed by $\Bbb Z$, i.e., $\{0\}\times \Bbb N\cup \{1\}\times \Bbb Z$ with lexicographic order. Or if you prefer it embedded into the real line: $\{\,\arctan n\mid n\in\Bbb N\,\}\cup\{4+\arctan k\mid k\in\Bbb Z\,\}$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, I have a question, You have $\Bbb N\cup \{1\}\cup \Bbb Z$. Isn't it just $\Bbb Z$?

Comment: @Karol I think it should be $(\{0\}×\mathbb N)∪(\{1\}×\mathbb Z)$ with the Lexicographical order: $(a,a')\le (b,b')$ if and only if $a<b$ or ($a=b$ and $a'≤ b'$). Where $a=0,1$ and if $a=0$ then $a'∈\Bbb N$, if $a=1$ then $a'∈\Bbb Z$(and the same for $b$)

Comment: Thank you very much. I wouldn't think of it myself.